# How many numbers can I put in a Maven project version

Tags: maven, version-control, pom.xml, karaf, version-numbering

I am developing a bundle to be installed on a Karaf container.
I tried to put a version based on six points **(0.0.0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)**. Its gets installed and become actif and functionnal. But when I list the bundles installed I see my bundle with only the first three zero and Snapshot **(0.0.0.SNAPSHOT)**.

Is there any limit to the number I can put in the project version?

Comment: There two worlds. Maven world there is no problem having multiple digits as you shown but in OSGi world you have only 3 digit versions...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After testing it appears that in OSGi world a version can have up to 4 digits.

Comment: The last 4th digit is as far as is know for a build number not for real difference...OSGi follows semver...or semver follows OSGi ;-)